# RequestContext se ejecuta dos veces

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, primefaces

quiero mandar a llamar una funcion de Js desde un bean de Jsf con RequestContext, pero por alguna extraña razón la función se ejecuta dos veces.

Este es el código de mi xhtml:

```
<h:form >
    <p:commandButton class="btn" 
        value="Llamar js Function" 
        action="#{developerController.foo}"/>
</h:form>
```

Este es el código de mi bean:

```
@Named(value = "developerController")
@SessionScoped
public class DeveloperController implements Serializable {

@EJB
QuoteManager quoteManager;

public DeveloperController() {

}

public void foo() {
    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    requestContext.execute("alert('Hola');");
}


}
```

¿Qué debo hacer para que el "alert()" se ejecute una en  lugar de dos veces?

Estoy usando primefaces 6.0 y Glassfish 4.1

Comment: Lo unico que se me ocurre es que cambies en nivel de scope que usa en el managed bean, por un request o por un view

Comment: No, ni así funciona, tengo la teoría de que es un bug de primefaces.

Comment: @Lcop al cambiarle el scope a request o view solo reduces su alcance a comparación del session. Esto no está asociado al número de veces que se ejecuta el request.

Comment: ¿Ese es todo el código para reproducir el problema? De ser así, sería bueno que también compartieses las versiones de JSF (¿Mojarra?) y PrimeFaces usadas en este ejemplo.

Comment: Ya agregué mis versiones de glassfish y de primefaces, pero no sé como ver mi versión de Mojarra.

Comment: Yo tuve ese problema, nada mas cambie el action por actionListener y trabaja muy bien.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza lo que mencionas lo se, lo que sucede es que en el ejemplo de primefaces no es claro el nivel de scope que se debe usar asi que por eso lo sugeri como comentario

Comment: JSF tiene dos implementaciones, Mojarra y Apache MyFaces. Como usas Glassfish 4, lo más probable es que uses Mojarra de implementación.

Comment: gibran en el ejm de primefaces lo usan con actionListener asi que podria probar lo que sugiere David Lopez, considerando que el actionListener es ajax por defecto en primefaces, mientras que el action siempre busca retornar la pagina a la que se va a redirigir

Comment: Tampoco funcionó con actionListener  :/

Comment: @Lcop [Differences between action and actionListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener). En resumen, debería funcionar con ambos o con ninguno. Y de preferencia, usa `action`, no `actionListener`.

Comment: Si agregas un postConstruct el alert, se ejecuta también dos veces?

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza **actionListener** en lugar de **action**, ya que el método action se utiliza para la redirección y debería devolver un String que debe coincidir con tus reglas de navegación.

Probablemente al ser un método que no devuelve nada te esté dando el problema al intentar redireccionarse a si mismo.

Saludos.